# Thin dependency workaround for mailcatcher gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, thin, mailcatcher

In order to test emails in my rails app, I tried adding the mailcatcher gem. When I first ran mailcatcher, I got an error with eventmachine that effectively broke the mailcatcher server. I realized this was due to the version of mailcatcher being used, but after I tried to update to a newer version, I am having dependency issues. I got the following error when I ran bundle:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "thin":
  In Gemfile:
    mailcatcher (>= 0.6.1) ruby depends on
      thin (~> 1.5.0) ruby

    thin (1.6.3)
```

Is there any possible workaround, or other suggestions? I don't want to lock thin at 1.5.0. Older versions of mailcatcher are broken, and the updated versions aren't playing nicely with thin. I may just find another gem to test emails...

Comment: Have you added mailcatcher to your app's Gemfile? You don't need to do this

Comment: I did. I'll try it independently.

Comment: Actually you don't need to put mail catcher in your gem file i think. Why not just install thin 1.5.0 and run mail catcher independently from your rails application. Your rails app can run on thin 1.6.3 in gem file and your mail catcher will use the 1.5.0. You can install both versions of thin at same time :)

Comment: Thanks. Mailcatcher runs now, but does has not caught the emails I sent via the rails console. Different problem. I have in config/environments/development.rb:     config.action_mailer.delivery_method       = :smtp     config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries    = true 
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings         = { address: "localhost", port: 1025 }

Comment: Just kidding. Was my own problem in rails. One of you add your response below and I'll mark it as answered. Thanks!!